# How to fixed table header row in struts2 display table

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

How to fixed table header row in struts2 display table..

Below code is in struts2 display table

```
<display:table id="approvalList" name="approvalList" pagesize="${PAGESIZE}" export="false"  style="width:934px;align:right;overflow: auto" class="tableHeading" requestURI="approval-list" >
<display:column  title="Reports"  sortable="false" style="width:11%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">111</display:column> 
<display:column  title="Project No."  sortable="false" style="width:13%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">222</display:column>
<display:column  title="Status"  sortable="false" style="width:16%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">333</display:column>   
<display:column  title="Client Name"  sortable="false" style="width:18%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">444</display:column>
<display:column  title="Project Name"  sortable="false" style="width:20%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">555</display:column>   
<display:column  title="Set No."  sortable="false" style="width:10%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">666</display:column>
<display:column  title="Placed Date"  sortable="false" style="width:12%;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;">777</display:column>                </display:table>
```

Above Code generates the below HTML Code.In that how to fixed table header row.

```
<table id="approvalList" style="width:934px;align:right;overflow: auto"  class="tableHeading">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Reports</th>
        <th>Project No.</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Set No.</th>
        <th>Placed Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>     
    <tr class="even">
        <td style="width:11%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">111</td>
        <td style="width:13%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">222</td>
        <td style="width:16%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">333</td>
        <td style="width:18%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">444</td>
        <td style="width:20%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">555</td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">666</td>
        <td style="width:12%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">777</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td style="width:11%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">111</td>
        <td style="width:13%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">222</td>
        <td style="width:16%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">333</td>
        <td style="width:18%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">444</td>
        <td style="width:20%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">555</td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">666</td>
        <td style="width:12%;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;">777</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do you mean?: table
{
table-layout:fixed;
}

Comment: no, he means a fixed header with the table scrolling... there're many solutions on the web, but displayTag is old and i guess none of those solutions will work on new browsers anymore. You have to trick a bit :/

Comment: Thanks **Andrea** but what is the solution for generated HTML code in that i want to fixed table header row.

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the table caption?

Comment: No I don't want to set table caption I want table header '<th>' fixed means freez the table header while scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

Struts do not give you that but CSS or/and Javascript does.

Try http://www.tablefixedheader.com/ or http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html.  Everything depends on your requirements.

Another recomendation, avoid inline styles (style attribute) and prefer CSS files and class attribute. They have many advantages, you have only to search it on google.

I hope this help you, any comment will be welcome.